# custom format cell in excel

Tags: excel, formatting

I have a question about custom format cell , Which codes or characters in custom format cell  should I use that when I copy a formula from another cell and paste in formatted cell then the result of formatted cell (displayed number) does not change and remain as before pasting?

More explanation
Suppose we have a table where the third column is the product of the first column multiplied by the second.
[image]

Then we change one of the cells of the third column using the custom format cell and the character “apple” as follows.
[image]
Now if we copy the second row cell of the third column and paste it in the fifth row cell of the third column, the word apple changes to the number 15.
My question is what character instead of “apple “ to use in the custom format cell that does not change the word apple after copying the second row of the third column and pasting in the fifth row of the third column? (for example add the characters "#*., @ and etc. with apple may be was the answer

Comment: If you copy the formula, then you're not copying any of the formatting. Formulas and formats are two separate things.

Comment: This post is WAY too ambiguous. Why custom format? Why copy and paste formula?

Comment: @BigBen that's true, but you can copy the contents of a cell and then paste formulas and NUMERIC formats under "Paste Special" menu option... which is why I questioned the "why custom format".

Comment: @sam1361 has your question been answered or do you still require a resolution on this?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I had two fields with floating point numbers which are divided by each other and the result of the calculation displayed on cell C1. I then copied the same two values down to the second row. I formatted cell C2 to use numeric format with two decimal values only. Lastly, I proceeded to copy the formula on C1 and paste it on cell C2 using "Paste Special --> Formula." You can see the cell format was preserved.

I don't understand this question because it lacks basic context. However, I think I was able to demonstrate that I was able to do what the OP said without "result of formatted cell not changing and remaining as before pasting."

**UPDATE**:

The example below shows a cell with a custom format of "apple" that formerly contained the formula a*b. After copying the contents of cell B2, I used "Paste Special" to paste the VALUE (nothing else) into cell B5. As you can see in the top-right of the image, the cell contains the value "2" but the custom format of "apple" is preserved.

[image]

Obviously, this is not a good example. Suppose that, instead of a custom format of "apple" I format that cell to contain a special format where I want to show a leading zero (if value is single digit) as well as two decimal places. The result is the same. The special formatting is preserved by "specially pasting" something other than the format of the cell.

If I repeat the same process as before, I can paste the value of "2" but it will be presented using the special (custom) format that I had before on the cell, because in Excel, the paste operation copies the value as well as all the metadata of the cell. To avoid this, "PASTE SPECIAL" is the option.

[image]

That said, there might be a way of protecting the worksheet to prevent formatting to be overridden in a paste operation. Since I am not an Excel super-user, I don't know if there is a way to lock this information globally. I assume there is a way, but I just don't know it.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. 
But that was not what I meant. In fact, I might ask the question, is it possible to define a format for a cell that contains a number that when we paste a formula into it , the number does not change in the cell ?

Comment: @sam1361 I think the answer is the same. There might be a way to protect the formats on each cell globally. However, when you want to "copy and paste" you need to do it using "Paste Special", if you want to preserve any of the cell formatting. You can decide what you want to "specially paste' in the destination cell.